# Why doesn't /0/g match in a string that contains zeroes?

Tags: java, regex

This code always returns "false" at last, even if Integer contains any zero:

```
Integer i = (int) rand(1, 200); // random [1;200)
String regexp = "/0/g";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(i.toString());

print(i);
print(m.matches());
```

What is the reason? I don't get where the mistake could be.

Needed: m.matches() = "true" if Integer contains one or more zero.

Comment: Um, your regular expression is looking for slashes and a `g` character... where do you expect those to come from?

Comment: It's Java here. Try `String regexp = ".*0.*";`.

Comment: You need to use find function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're giving the regular expression incorrectly. The string you give [`Pattern.compile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-) is *just* the text of the expression, without `/` on either side, and without flags; flags are specified separately.

So in your case, you'd just want:

```
String regexp = "0";
```

There's no "global" flag; instead, you use the methods on the resulting `Matcher` as appropriate to what you're doing.

> Needed: m.matches() = "true" if Integer contains one or more zero.

Then you don't want to use `Matcher#matches`, you want `Match#find`. Or if you *need* to use `Matcher#matches`, the expression would be:

```
String regexp = ".*0.*";
```

...e.g., any number of any character, then a 0, then any number of any character. That way, the entire string can match the expression.

---

Of course, if you just want to know there's a zero, it's much simpler to just use

```
boolean flag = String.valueOf(i).indexOf('0') != -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you don't need a regex at all since you are looking for a literal character, use `indexOf`:

```
if (Str.indexOf( '0' ) != -1) {
...
```

about your original pattern:

regex don't need to be enclosed between delimiters in Java, so slashes are useless. The global modifier isn't needed too because the global nature is determined by the method you choose. *(in other words, the only way to obtain several results is to use the `find` method in a loop to obtain the different results)*

Answer (score 0):

```
print(m.find());
```

Matcher will match from beginning.Use `find` as `0` input is not possible in your case.

Using find will enable you to locate `0` anywhere in the string.

`matches` tries to match the expression against the entire string and implicitly add a ^ at the start and $ at the end of your pattern, meaning it will not look for a substring. Hence `false`.

Also change your regex to `"0"` as suggested by the other answer.

Comment: Not me, but simply changed to `find` won't solve the problem. *`String regexp = "/0/g";`*

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String regexp = ".*0.*";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(i.toString());

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
}
```

Regex :

[image]